# Questions regarding backward propagation

Tags: neural-network, numerical

I am reading article regarding backward propagation https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/ . Lets say if I follow the example in the article but using only 3 node, with the 1st node an input, 2nd node the hidden layer and 3rd node the output so at 2nd node, the result is I1*W1+B1 which is feed into the logistic function and this outputs(O2) is then feed into the last node O2(W2)+B2 that is finally feed into the logistic function again.

a)Lets say initially I using w1=0.4 and get the result of E1, then using w1=0.401 to get the result of E2 again. Is this represent numerical approximation for dE/dw1=(E2-E1)/(0.401-0.4)?

b)Can this error be represent as an expansion of taylor series around E(w1)?
$$E(w1+h)=E(w1)+h*\frac{dE}{dw1}+\frac{1}{2}h^2\frac{d^2E}{dw1^2}+...?$$

c)Is it possible to use similar runge kutta method to obtain higher order of the error